# Does it kill the tree if I remove its surface roots?

Tags: roots

This is my first year in my current house and I have a tree that I don't know its type. I am attaching a picture of this tree. I noticed that its roots are running underneath some of the yard pavers and moved them sideways and upward. I wanted to know if I can cut the root that is going under the pavers without killing the tree.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is much to close to the house - and to your neighbour's garden, unless he/she doesn't mind having a garden full of your tree roots! I would get rid of it completely before it does some more serious damage than lifting a few paving slabs.